# Creating indefinate amount of objects to put in a deque

Tags: java, queue, deque

I am trying to create a user defined deque that stores a user defined amount objects.  I create an item object and give it the values or item# and price, than store the object in a deque.  so far my Main consists of a singular item.  Every time I set the item it over writes the previously stored item values with the most recent.  How can i go about creating an indefinate amount of items to store them all?

Main

```
import java.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyDequeApp {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //variables
    String userinNum;
    double userinPrice;
    int queOp;

    //creating new Item
    Item item1= new Item();

    //creating new Scanner      
    Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);

    //user input number of elements in the deque
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the que");
    int queElm=scan1.nextInt();     
    MyDeque theQueue=new MyDeque(queElm);

    //do/while so while user selects 1-7 they stay in the switch/case
    do
    {
        //switch/case menu
        System.out.println("1. Insert to front");
        System.out.println("2. Insert to rear");
        System.out.println("3. Remove from front");
        System.out.println("4. Remove from rear");
        System.out.println("5. Peek front");
        System.out.println("6. Peek rear");
        System.out.println("7. Display deque");
        System.out.println("Anything else to Quit");

        //user input the case number
        queOp=scan1.nextInt();
        scan1.nextLine();

        switch(queOp)
        {
            //insert to front
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter an item number");
                userinNum=scan1.nextLine();
                item1.setNum(userinNum);
                System.out.println("Enter a price");
                userinPrice=scan1.nextDouble();
                scan1.nextLine();
                item1.setPrice(userinPrice);
                System.out.println(item1.toString());
                theQueue.insertFront(item1);
                    break;

            //insert to rear
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter an item numbeR");
                userinNum=scan1.nextLine();
                item1.setNum(userinNum);
                System.out.println("Enter a pricE");
                userinPrice=scan1.nextDouble();
                scan1.nextLine();
                item1.setPrice(userinPrice);
                System.out.println(item1.toString());
                theQueue.insertFront(item1);
                theQueue.insertRear(item1);
                    break;

            //remove from front
            case 3:
                theQueue.removeFront();
                    break;

            //remove from rear
            case 4:
                theQueue.removeRear();
                    break;

            //peek front
            case 5:
                System.out.println(theQueue.peekFront());
                    break;

            //peek rear
            case 6:
                System.out.println(theQueue.peekRear());
                    break;

            //display the deque
            case 7: 
                System.out.println(theQueue.toString());
                    break;

            //quit
            default:
                    break;


        }

    }while(queOp>0 && queOp<8); 

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add

```
item1= new Item();
```

either after you're done with one and have added it to your queue, or in a place before you go to enter data for a new one, otherwise the program thinks item1 is always the same item.

Comment: Im still a little unclear.  Do you mean add as in declare item2, item3, item 4 etc.? or with a Item (variable)?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: or possibly incrementing?

Comment: just how it's written already in your code, but you need to move that part down into the loop so the loop is also creating the new item. The confusing part here is that item1 will actually be different items each time through the loop but have the same name in the loop itself while being a different object in your queue.